# Mapbox-gl-js Custom Layer - Background Map goes white when clearing using threejs renderer

Tags: javascript, three.js, mapbox-gl-js

Copied from github [issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/9499),

Hello, I was experimenting with loading models using the custom layer interface and ran into a problem. I'm actually drawing the custom layer through DeckGL and react-map-gl, however I believe that the heart of the problem lies in the custom layer which belongs here so I'm asking the question here. Anyways the problem is pretty similar to issue #[8936](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/8936). However the solution there doesn't work but infact, it's the cause of the problem as far as I understood. If you try clearing manually or set `renderer.autoClear` to true, the underlying map disappears and only a white background is shown with the model laid on top.

This can be easily seen using the official [example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/) and it's jsfiddle. Just set `autoClear` to true.

I was actually experimenting with using post processing, which requires to use `composer.render` instead of `renderer.render` and the former clears the buffers during passes.

I thought this was due to a non transparent canvas issue perhaps and initialized the threejs renderer with a separate canvas, with `alpha` set to true and setting the clear color to all 0's but on alpha 0, it shows white and if you increase alpha it starts showing whatever `clearColor` was set to. It doesn't show the underlying mapbox canvas.

A screencap to demonstrate clearly whats the problem,

clearColor all 0's and alpha 0.
[image]

ClearColor is red and alpha is 0.2.
[image]

Intended picture when using clearing,
[image]

Update:- Ok it seems like the transparency is working fine. This is because when I changed the clearColor to red and alpha to `0.4` I noticed there was a small time period where the map was shown with a red overlay like so
[image]

However as soon as the model appears, the map disappears and the image resembles the second one. So something's wrong there.